# Sending a variable to a textbox using delegates

Tags: c#, variables, textbox, delegates

How can I get or reference the variable `k` that I've created in `button1_Click()`?

Consider that I cannot make it public or static. Meanwhile I want the value of this varible to be sent to `textbox.text`;

How can this be done?

```
    public delegate string fac(int x);
    public static fac intostring = factory;

    public static string factory(int x)
    {
        string inst = x.ToString();
        return inst;
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        static public string s = intostring(/*here*/);
            public string Text;

        public MyClass(Form Form1)
        {
            var textbox = Form1.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault();
            Text = ((TextBox)textbox).Text = (s);
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int k = 1;
        intostring(k);
        MyClass my = new MyClass(this);
    }
```

Comment: WHat are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want a variabe like k to be sent to the fac delegate and then go to change the "s string" I mean when I click on button1

Comment: I think you are misusing the Static construct. Static vars should not rely on any initialization information from outside the class. why do you need s to be STatic? would Readonly work? then you could pass k as a constructor parameter and be assured that it can;t be changed by clients.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the variable `k`'s scope in button1_Click is the function `button1_Click` and you can't get a reference to it outside the scope of that function!

Then, the line `intostring(k);` doesn't really do anything uselful because you are not using the returned result of invoking the delegate.

To set the Text of the TextBox to the value of k, you could simply just do that right there:

```
int k = 1;
var textbox = Form1.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault();
((TextBox)textbox).Text = k
```

Comment: And second? They could still pass it into a MyClass constructor or elaborately as a delegate, yet again in a MyClass constructor or like.

Comment: I defined it outside button1_Click() function scope and  it worked.